# Why is a UIBarButtonItems width 0 when it's the minimum size

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode6

I have a `UIBarButton` in InterfaceBuilder:

[image]

But when the width is the minimum size (without hiding any of the button), the width becomes zero:

[image]

When you increase the width to anything but the minimum, all is right with the world:

[image]

[image]

I checked the width programmatically and sure enough, the width is zero when it's the minimum size. When you increase the size by 1 or more, the width is correct. Is this a bug or is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 means it takes the calculated minimum size based on the button text, so it isn't a bug, it's a feature. Note that you can't make the button smaller than this minimum size, because the text of a toolbar button item should not change (and the text should always be visible).

Comment: Cool, I wish that they'd remove that "feature". Getting 0 back for  a bar button item that is clearly not 0 width, is not exactly expected behavior. But the reasoning does make sense.